# creating midi files using python or installing midiutil

Tags: python, macos, terminal, installation, midi

The stumbling block I'm currently at, trying to use MIDIUtil (https://midiutil.readthedocs.io/en/1.2.1/), is the installation. I have managed to get MIDIUtil installed, but I've been butting heads with "python setup.py install" for a while. For some reason, I can't get the terminal to recognise the file exists. I can't just drag the file onto the terminal as the install file uses other files in the same folder, that the terminal then can't find. What I suspect is that I have misunderstood something in regards to what folder branch it's actually set to (and looking through).

The attached image just shows me trying to run the installation, which folder the file is in, and that the file exists.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/drpMf.png

Comment: SO is not a forum. If you have a new question, ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setup.py` file is stored in `/Users/esca/MIDIUtil`.

The shell prompt shows that its current directory is your home directory, i.e., `/Users/esca`.

You have to change into the `MIDIUtil` directory first:

```
cd MIDIUtil
python setup.py install
```

Comment: I thought it was something like that :) That let me install it, but I don't think the installation went entirely correct (updating the question now)